# Eclipse Juno not recognizing user defined dictionary has been specified

Tags: dictionary, eclipse-juno, suse

I'm a new user to Eclipse (Juno) with SUSE 11 Linux,I am looking for specifying a user defined dictionary so that I can stop all the "Trolltech" and "Qt" references in my Qt projects showing up as spelling errors, without turning off all spell checking.

I found following instructions online, I select **Window | Preferences | Editors | Text Editors | Spelling** and get a panel including a field in which to specify a user defined dictionary.  I gather all this needs to be, is a text file.  I have tried two variations for this:

As root,

1. created an **/opt/eclipse/dictionary/dictionary.txt** file, file
   permissions set 777 but higher level directories 755s
2. created a **/dictionary/dictionary.txt** file, both directory and file permissions
   set 777.

I have at this point, in each case,

1. specified the full (absolute) path to one of these files in the
   "User defined dictionary" field,
2. clicked either **Apply | OK** to set the path, or just **OK**, exiting the dialog
3. seen no change in the Eclipse editor, which still shows these terms as misspellings
4. at the level of the project, attempted **Refresh** of the project from
   the right-mouse popup menu
5. tried re-indexing at the level of the project using **Index | Rebuild** from the right-mouse popup menu
6. tried refreshing files at the level of the project using **Index |
   Freshen All Files** from the right-mouse popup menu (no reason
   to believe that either of steps 5 or 6 will help, but I'm basically
   trying everything that seems available to be tried)
7. closed and re-opened the project
8. closed and re-opened the IDE.

When I restart the IDE and go back into **Window | Preferences**, etc., the panel shows the dictionary text file I've specified AS specified, but there seems to be no functional recognition of this by the IDE.

Adding to the joy, when I hover above either of the "errors" I'd like to stop seeing, I don't get the quick fix option of adding the error word to the dictionary, because last week I ticked the option that said "don't prompt to add to a dictionary, if no dictionary exists".  Doesn't appear that any dictionary is being recognized as existing.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing, here?

Comment: OK, I figured it out.  The thing none of the instructions I'd read mentioned, is that in the Windows | Preferences etc., panel, you have to change from "Default spelling engine" to "C/C++ spelling engine".  Then you re-specify the dictionary and it works.

Comment: Than you, it works. You should add the answer.

Comment: Dorothy, it is perfectly fine on stackoverflow to answer your own question and accept it.  It will be useful for future generations of unlucky eclipse users.

Answer (score 8):

I'm just adding this here because Dorothy didn't answer his own question even after 3 years. This will stop the question showing up in the unanswered category and provide space for newer questions.

Dorothy Wight:

> OK, I figured it out. The thing none of the instructions I'd read mentioned, is that in the Windows | Preferences etc., panel, you have to change from "Default spelling engine" to "C/C++ spelling engine". Then you re-specify the dictionary and it works.